# Order Statistics with two Groups of Draws

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, order-statistics

Let $X_{1},X_{2},\ldots,X_{m},\ldots,X_{n}$ be independently drawn from a distribution $F$ and let $Y_{k}^{(n)}$ be the $k$-th order statistic (Convention: $Y_{1}^{(n)}>Y_{2}^{(n)}>\cdots>Y_{n}^{(n)}$). What is the probability distribution  of the maximum of $Y_{1}^{(n)}$ and $Y_{2}^{(m)}+a$ with $a$ some positive constant. Note that the first order statistic is taken over the whole $n$ draws, while the second order statistic is taken over the subsample of $m$ draws.

So how is $\max\{Y_1^{(n)},Y_2^{(m)}+a\}$ distributed? I think there are 2 possibilities:

1. The first order statistic of $n$ is not in the $m$ group, then we look at the maximum between the highest draw out of $n-m$ and the second highest draw out of $m$ plus $a$. These two would be independent, so the maximum would just be the product of the two cdfs., \begin{equation}
   P\big\{\max\{Y_1^{(n-m)},Y_2^{(m)}+a\}\big\}=F^{(n-m)}_{1}(x)F^{(m)}_{2}(x-a)
   \end{equation}
2. The first order statistic of $n$ is in the $m$ group, then we look at the maximum between the highest draw out of $m$ and the second highest draw out of $m$ plus $a$, which is from an 
   [earlier question here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1742450/density-of-maximum-of-order-statistics/1742484#1742484) on SE given by  \begin{equation}
   P\big\{\max\left \{Y_{1}^{(m)},Y_{2}^{(m)}+a\right \}<x\big\}=mF(x-a)^{m-1}F(x)-(m-1)F(x-a)^{m}
   \end{equation}

With this reasoning the probability distribution of $\max\{Y_1^{(n)},Y_2^{(m)}+a\}$ would be given by
\begin{gather}
P\big\{Y_{1}^{(n)}\notin \text{Group m} \big\}P\big\{\max\{Y_{1}^{(n-m)},Y_{2}^{(m)}+a\}<x\big\} \\
+ P\big\{Y_{1}^{(n)}\in \text{Group m} \big\}P\big\{\max\{Y_{1}^{(m)},Y_{2}^{(m)}+a\}<x\big\}\\
=\Big(1-\frac{m}{n}\Big)\Big(\underbrace{F(x)^{n-m}}_{=F^{(n-m)}_{1}(x)}\underbrace{\big(mF(x-a)^{m-1}-(m-1)F(x-a)^{m}\big)}_{=F^{(m)}_{2}(x-a)}\Big)\\
+\frac{m}{n}\Big(\underbrace{mF(x-a)^{m-1}F(x)-(m-1)F(x-a)^{m}}_{=P\big\{\max\left \{Y_{1}^{(m)},Y_{2}^{(m)}+a\right \}<x\big\}}\Big).
\end{gather}

Did I miss something?

Answer (score 1):

No, you're ignoring various dependencies. In particular, where you write "These two would be independent", they're not; you're including cases where $Y_1^{(n-m)}\lt Y_2^{(m)}$, despite previously assuming that $Y_1^{(n)}$ is greater than the first $m$ values.

The probability that exactly $k$ of the values are in $(x-a,x]$ and the other $n-k$ are at most $x-a$ is

$$
\binom nkF(x-a)^{n-k}\left(F(x)-F(x-a)\right)^k.
$$

The probability that the first $m$ samples are all among the $k$ values or $m-1$ of them are among the $k$ values and one isn't is

$$
\frac{\binom km+(n-k)\binom k{m-1}}{\binom nm}\;,
$$

Thus the desired probability is

$$
\binom nm^{-1}\sum_{k=m}^n\left(\binom km+(n-k)\binom k{m-1}\right)\binom nkF(x-a)^{n-k}\left(F(x)-F(x-a)\right)^k.
$$

Comment: Hi! I have just realized that there must be an error somewhere, the probability at the end evaluates to a lot larger than 1... I think I've spotted one error: in the first fraction it should read  \begin{equation}
\frac{\binom{i}{m}+(n-i)\binom{i}{m-1}}{\binom{n}{m}}, 
\end{equation}without the m. But still, the expression is larger than 1 for the Uniform Distribution as an example... Thanks a lot!

Comment: @testrado: Could you give specific values of $m,n,a,x$ for which you get probabilities $\gt1$? I couldn't find any in a brief check. I believe the factor $m$ in that first fraction is right; it takes into account that you can select any of the $m$ samples not to be among the $k$ values.

Comment: m=3 n=15 a=0.5 and x=0.5 yields 13.625 with the uniform distribution on [0,1].

Comment: Ok I thought it was not needed because as I understand it, this would choose one of the m being larger and being one of the n-k, which would choose it twice as I understand it.... Thank you very much for looking into it again!

Comment: @testrado: You were right; there was a $+$ between the factors that shouldn't have been there -- I fixed that -- I hope it comes out right now?

Comment: oh yes I totally missed that one too. I got one issue left: the term $$
\frac{\binom km+m(n-k)\binom k{m-1}}{\binom nm}\;,
$$ becomes larger than 1 too for the same parameters than before and with small k while it stays below or equal to 0 without the $m$... Is it possible that the m does not belong there after all? The problem is that if it doesn't belong there I have no idea why the (n-k) should be there and vice versa.... Thanks!

Comment: Also I think that the probabilities got too small now for the whole expression to make sense, but that may be my code that I'll have to recheck over the weekend. Thanks a lot already!

Comment: @testrado: I'm very sorry, you're right again. I should have checked more thoroughly when you first pointed out the error. The $m$ indeed doesn't belong there, since $\binom km$, $\binom k{m-1}$ and $\binom nm$ count unordered samples whereas the factor $m$ would be appropriate if we were counting ordered samples. I don't understand why you link it to the $n-k$, though. This isn't related to order but to a single choice; perhaps the form

$$
\binom{n-k}0\binom km+\binom{n-k}1\binom k{m-1}
$$

for the numerator makes that a bit clearer.

Comment: @testrado:  About the probabilities getting too small, I'll await your rechecking of the code.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, gotta love university administration... well :-)

Comment: Taking the limit of $a$ to 0 should yield the first order statistic of $n$ draws right? I think this does not happen atm if I am not mistaken, so I tried modifying the second part of the expression but was not successful yet. Could you maybe take another look?

Comment: (I missed the 5 min window) The expression goes to 0 if I am not mistaken for $a\rightarrow 0$

Comment: Or should the second expression maybe read $$
\binom nkF(x-a)^{k}\left(F(x)-F(x-a)\right)^{n-k}
$$Then the limit becomes $$F^n(x)=F^{(n)}_1(x)$$